# HTTP MVC Error | Integrating React with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

I am working on a project to incorporate React with Asp.net to get more familiar with react. I keep getting the error shown in the image below.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11H6P.png)

I am currently following along a tutorial and have done the proper steps and swapped the RouteConfig.cs to the default controller. Even when I try to to manually go to /default it still shows the error.

Link for tutorial I am following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bnFgGYooDCM

Below is the code for my RouteConfig.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="default", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Below is the code for my DefaultController:

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Below is my current Solution Explorer setup.

[Solution Explorer Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TBrn.png)

I believe my Views and naming and everything matches up. I have searched almost everywhere to find a solution for this but have come up with nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whole line that contains `<dotless ....>` in Web.config

Comment: There is no line that has <dotless ...>. I updated the post to show the web.config code

EDIT: I found the line and removed it up still displays an error. Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I have downloaded the NuGets for the System.Web.Mvc as i ran into that issue earlier; not sure if its the same thing or not